# "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Promise<FirmDoc>'" // "Type '() => Promise<string[]>' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'."

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a "Firm" microservice that registers a firm and users within the firm before a user can sign up for the web application. I am running tests on my route handlers and getting an error of "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Promise'". Where am I going wrong?

When I mark the global.signin function as async and add `await buildFirm()` as well as replace `` return [`session=${base64}`]; `` with ...

```
  const cookie = [`session=${base64}`];
  return new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(cookie);
  })
```

the error on id goes away, but I get a new error on `global.signin` saying "Type '() => Promise<string[]>' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
Type 'Promise<string[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more."

**setup.ts** *(test setup)*:

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { Firm, FirmDoc } from '../models/firm';
declare global {
  var rootsignin: () => string[];
}

declare global {
  var signin: () => string[];
}

jest.mock("../nats-wrapper");

let mongo: any;
beforeAll(async () => {
  jest.setTimeout(10000)
  process.env.JWT_KEY = "asdfasdf";
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

  const mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  const mongoUri = mongo.getUri();

  await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {});
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

  for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});

afterAll(async () => {
  if (mongo) {
    await mongo.stop();
  }
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});

global.rootsignin = () => {
  const payload = {
    id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString(),
    email: "test@test.com",
    name: 'Root User',
    root: true,
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_KEY!);

  const session = { jwt: token };

  const sessionJSON = JSON.stringify(session);

  const base64 = Buffer.from(sessionJSON).toString("base64");

  return [`session=${base64}`];
};

const buildFirm = async () => {
  const firm = Firm.build({
    domain: ['@test.com'],
    name: 'Test Firm',
    type: 'Private Equity'
  });
  await firm.save();

  return firm;
}

global.signin = () => {
  const firm = buildFirm();

  const payload = {
    id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString(),
    email: "test@test.com",
    name: 'Test Name',
    firmId: firm.id,   // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    root: false,
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_KEY!);

  const session = { jwt: token };

  const sessionJSON = JSON.stringify(session);

  const base64 = Buffer.from(sessionJSON).toString("base64");

  return [`session=${base64}`];
};
```

**firm.ts** *(Firm Model)*:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { FirmStatus } from "@mavata/common";

export { FirmStatus };


// 1. Interface #1 WHAT IT TAKES TO CREATE A Firm
// An interface that describes the properties
// that are requried to create a new Firm
interface FirmAttrs {
  id?: string;
  domain: string[];
  name: string;
  type?: string;
}

// Interface #2 WHAT THE ENTIRE COLLECTION OF FIRMS LOOKS LIKE (METHODS ASSOCIATED WITH THE Firm MODEL)
// An interface that describes the properties
// that a Firm Model has
interface FirmModel extends mongoose.Model<FirmDoc> {
  build(attrs: FirmAttrs): FirmDoc;
  deleteById(id: string): FirmDoc;
}

// Interface #3 WHAT PROPERTIES A SINGLE Firm HAS
// An interface that describes the properties
// that a Firm Document has
export interface FirmDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  domain: string[];
  status: FirmStatus;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  users: string[];
  companies: string[];
}

const firmSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  domain: [{
    type: String,
    required: true
  }],
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: Object.values(FirmStatus),
    default: FirmStatus.Created,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: false
  },
  users: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    default: [],
    required: true
  }],
  companies: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company',
    default: [],
    required: true
  }]
},
{
  // UNCOMMON to be transformation logic inside of a model
  // this is defining how some data inside of our model should be VIEWED and transmitted along the network
  toJSON: {
    transform(doc, ret) {
      ret.id = ret._id;     // rename _id property to id
      delete ret._id;       // delete the _id property off the object
      delete ret.__v;       // delete useless property
    }
  }
});

// middleware function
// if we used arrow function rather than function declaration as seen below, then
// references to 'this' would refer to THIS Firms.ts file rather than 
// refer to the 'Firm' trying to be persisted in the database
firmSchema.pre('save', async function(done) {
  // when a Firm instance is being updated, we only want to check if the password has changed
  // so only attempt to hash the password if it has been modified
  console.log('firm saved of type ', this.type);
  done();
});

firmSchema.statics.build = (attrs: FirmAttrs) => {
  return new Firm(attrs);
};

firmSchema.statics.deleteById = async (id: string) => {
  return await Firm.deleteOne({ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)});
};

const Firm = mongoose.model<FirmDoc, FirmModel>('Firm', firmSchema);

export { Firm };
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are declaring that signin will return an array of strings

```
declare global {
  var signin: () => string[];
}
```

Since `buildFirm` is asynchronous, you are correct in the need to `await` it before you can use it in `firm.id`. To `await` it, you must make `signin` an `async` function. This also means the function now returns a `Promise`.

```
declare global {
   var signin: () => Promise<string[]>
}
```

You most likely don't need the `declare global` blocks at all though.